# finding my py modules in sub folders, from the main application working dir

Tags: python-2.7

this question might have been asked before, but I could not find it.

I am on a Linux box. I have py app that runs from a folder called /avt. (example)
I did not write this code, and it has about 12 modules that go with it. I was the lucky engineer to inherit this mess.
this app imports other modules that live under this dir /avt/bin
I want to be able find my modules in the /bin dir no matter where the current working dir is. sometimes the app changes dir to some other sub folders to perform some file I/O. Then should return, but seems like sometimes it does not make it back, because the code will error out with "no such file or directory" error. so I want to test for working dir each time before I do any file I/O to the /bin dir.
As an example, I want to create files in /bin, and then later open those files and read data from them. How can I test to make sure my current working dir is always /avt? and if it is not, then ch.dir to it? Note: it also has to be portable code meaning if must run on any directory structure on any Linux machine.

I tried this code, but it is not very clean I think. Python is not my main language. Is this coding proper and will it work for this? forgive me I don't know how to format it for this forum.

```
Avtfolder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(inspect.getfile( inspect.currentframe() ))[0]))
if Avtfolder not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, Avtfolder)

if Avtfolder.__contains__('/avt'): 

    modfilespath = Avtfolder + '/bin'
    print 'bin dir is ' + modfilespath
else:
    print 'directory lost...'
#write some code here that changes to the root /avt dir
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a few notes.

First, I'm afraid you are mixing up two problems (or I couldn't tell from the question which one you're facing). These problems are:

1. I/O to files that can reside in different directories on different machines
2. Importing Python modules used by your app that can also be in slightly different locations.

The title of the question and some of the text suggests you're dealing with problem 2, whereas  references to I/O and "no such file or directory" error point to problem 1.

Those are, however, separate problems and are treated separately. I won't be able to give the exact recipes on both, but here are some suggestions:

**For problem 1**: I don't think it's a good idea to do some I/O, create files, etc. in the folder where the user installs the Python libraries. It's a folder for Python modules, not data. Also, if the library is installed via `setup.py`, using `pip` or `easy_install` (if it isn't the case now, that can change in the future) then the program will probably habe insufficient permissions to write there, unless invoked as `root`. And that's right. Create files somewhere else.

As to "how to track the directory changes" part: I must confess I don't quite understand what you mean. Why do you even using the concept of "current directory"? In my mind you should just have some variable such as `write_path`, `data_path`, etc. and the code would be

```
data = open(os.path.join(data_path, 'data.foo'))
dump = open(os.path.join(write_path, 'dump.bar'), 'w')
```

etc.

Why do you even care where are your libraries located? I don't think it's right, I'd change that. This `inspect.currentframe()` stuff smells like you really need to rethink the design of the library.

Now, what the location of the libraries matters for is **Problem 2**. But again, the *absolute* path shouldn't matter (if it does, change that!). You only need all the modules to be inside one folder (or its subfolders). If they are in the same folder, you're good. `import foo` will just work. If some are in subfolders, those subfolders should have a file named `__init__.py` in them, and then they will be seen as modules by Python interpreter, so you'll be able to do `from foo import bar`, where `foo` is a subfolder with `__init__.py` and `bar.py` in it.

So, try to rewrite it so that you don't depend on where the `.py` files are. You really shouldn't need to use `inspect` there at all. On another note, don't use special methods like `__contains__` directly unless you really need to. `if '/avt' in Avtfolder` will do the same.

Comment: I guess I have not been clear. yes, the code (you call it my libraries) reside in a sub folder called /bin. but the main app.py resided one folder up. In the /bin folder, I create several "temp" files using f = open(filename). Then late I open them to parse data, and then delete the files. Sometimes the application errors when it can't find the temp files to open. Somehow it does not know they reside in the sub-folder of /bin.

Comment: @David Okay, my point is it's not a good idea. Also, if the files are deleted in the end, you can clean things up by using the [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) module.

Comment: good advise, but I'm not getting a solution out of this conversation. This project has over 20 .py files, the previous owner of these files, used the os.chdir() 22 times! yes, he was jumping all over the place. I'm just trying to clean it up some so the code does not need to jump from folder to folder. crazy! how can I just give it an explist path? and have it find the bin folder? sorry I am ignorant. I don't know Linux much and I don't know python much.

Comment: The idea is once you create a file, don't "forget" it. Keep the file object or at least file path in some variable and access it later. I'm sorry that I'm not able to give more specific advice, but I don't see the code.